# How to make a MacBook Pro drive 2 monitors without overheating?

Tags: displayport

I have a MacBook Pro 15, 2017 Radeon Pro 560, and have 2 1440p 144Hz monitors. I tried using a dongle with HDMI and it only drives 60hz and overheats. To solve overheating what do I need to do?

1. Buy an EGPU?
2. Get two Thunderbolt to DisplayPort?
3. Get a CaliDigit Dock?
4. Get a better dongle?

I want my MacBook Pro screen to always be on with two monitors, with Ethernet and not throttle the CPU and overheating. I just don't know what to do or get to make sure I don't run into overheating problems.

I hope someone has a similar problem and can point me to the right direction.

Comment: DisplayPort for starers

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! How hot is your computer getting? You can check with something like iStats or Glances. What issue are you facing when the computer gets hot? Fan noise, degraded performance, something else?